# PoE only data and power over network

Tags: network, power-over-ethernet

Is ethernet(PoE)
the only (power and data) over the network.
I did google this

I'm dyslexic and dysgraphic
so
English

I tryed

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

IEEE PoE (*Power over MDI*) is the only standard for running power over a network cable, consisting of the original PoE 802.3af (12.95 W), the improved "PoE+" 802.3at (25.5 W) and the latest "4PPoE" 802.3bt (71 W).

There is a large number of proprietary variants out there as well. Most of them are not interoperable and it's possible to damage the hardware when using them in ways that are not intended, even accidentally. The IEEE standards use device signatures and are carefully designed to not apply power when the end device isn't showing such a signature.

Comment: For ethernet, yes. For other "data" systems, there are other methods/standards. Eg. any line powered telco hardware, old analog POTS phones, BPL (which is sort of the opposite -- data over a power line), ... All of these (even PoE) are basically a DC bias on an otherwise AC system.